# Trying to understand - IN (Subquery with UNION)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, union

I'm trying to understand why Query 1 works, but Query 2 doesn't. How does the UNION affect the execution?

I understand that there's implicit conversions taking place. I'm not after a fix, best-practice or performance, just trying to understand the reasoning.

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (ID INT, TXT VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (ID INT, T2Fk INT)

INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES(1, '1'), (2, '2'), (3, '3'), (4, 'AAA')
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES(1, 1), (2, 3)
                    
-- Query 1
SELECT * FROM @T2 WHERE T2Fk IN (SELECT TXT FROM @T1 WHERE ID IN (1,2,3))
-- Query 2
SELECT * FROM @T2 WHERE T2Fk IN (SELECT TXT FROM @T1 WHERE ID IN (1,2) UNION SELECT '3')
```

Thanks

Comment: SQL is declarative. The engine is free to chose whatever path through your data it wants - you cannot depend on short-circuiting to avoid your logic / schema errors. And that ultimately is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why SQL will run fine for first one, but not for the second one.  SQL is converting your T2FK from an VARCHAR(10) to a INT and that is causing the failure on the second query.  Best practice is to have comparing values of the same type.  If you convert T2Fk to a VARCHAR(10) your second query also works.

```
-- Query 2
SELECT * FROM @T2 WHERE CAST(T2Fk AS VARCHAR(10)) IN (SELECT TXT FROM @T1 WHERE ID IN (1,2) UNION SELECT '3')
```

Comment: The rules for [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) have the conversion going the other way: The `TXT` values need to be converted to `int` since it is the "higher" data type. You are eliminating the `int` from the left side of the `in` so that both sides are strings and no conversion is needed.

Comment: @HABO, the implicit conversion is what I'm saying is the issue.  You are right though SQL is converting to an INT and not to a varchar.  The first query works because the execution plan eliminates the AAA for 4 before the conversion.  The second one fails because it does not eliminate that record.  I don't get why SQL decides to eliminate the record first in the one, but not the other.

Comment: You can look at the _execution plan_ for each query to see the order in which operations are being performed. They are surprisingly different. As for _why_, a [Magic 8-Ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_8-Ball) may be the best guide as to the whims of the query optimizer. SMor's comment to the OP is correct: You use SQL to state what you want, not how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the table definition, let say that SQL accept a numer like 3 with no ' ', that's why your firs Query works, but in the second you are traying to pass a varchar as Int   in the position. if you make a Change in T2Fk int and put is as Varchar to it will work.

DECLARE @T1 TABLE (ID INT, TXT VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (ID int, T2Fk varchar(10))

And then your Queries  both will work